# This ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError makes absolutely no sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

### This problem has me contemplating retiring from programming and becoming a farmer..

I have a controller that calls a function, and then creates a Model instance with the returned hash.

Here's a sample run:

```
details = getPhoneDetails(params)
phone = PhoneNumber.create(details)
# => ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

What? Let's inspect the phone Hash:

```
abort(details.inspect) # => {number: "1234", country_code: "1"}
```

That looks right .. Hmm, how about I copy and paste that directly into the `create`:

```
Phone.create({number: "1234", country_code: "1"}); # works fine!
```

### That doesn't make sense

Why doesn't the first one work! I'm passing the SAME VALUES

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby on Rails 4 is [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) it's kind of blacklist for attributes, in case you know about Strong Parameters, are you able to provide for us permit params function?